# Design pattern for decoupling master from slave, and creating a third party, for generic implementation?

Tags: design-patterns

What is a design pattern that decouples a relationship between a master and a slave, and inserts an intermediary for generic use?

Example:

1. A colorpicker; User clicks on a little color box, and a flyout with a color wheel is displayed.
2. A datepicker: User clicks on a drop-down, and a calendar appears, allowing them to select a date
3. A select widget: User clicks a little down arrow, and is able to select from a list.

[image]

All of the above have a master-slave arrangement. User interaction with master triggers action from slave.

If we generalize this component, we can decouple the two, and insert an intermediary. That is, create three classes:

- master: Generates generic events
- intermediary: Enables  between master and slave
- slave: Responds to generic events

Now, we can generically implement a colorpicker, datepicker, and select widgets using this structure.

What is this design pattern called? Thx, Keith :^)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

Its purpose is not specifically to facilitate a "master-slave" relationship, but it does specify the intermediary you describe in order to further decouple two (or more) entities that must interact without having concrete references to one another.

Interesting to note is that the Mediator pattern can be implemented using the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be a factory pattern:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The salient feature here seems to be neither the so-called *master* nor the *slave* but rather the event-driven nature of their relationship. Consequently, I would say the [Observer pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) is most appropriate.